# How to execute sqlplus command on linux container using c# code

Tags: c#, linux, sqlplus, docker-container

I need to execute sqlplus command through c# application on the linux container. I tried below command. Its working fine through putty but not working from c# code. Infact it is locking the account. Can someone tell me the correct syntax of sqlplus command which works on linux container through c# app.

So far i have tried below ccommand

```
echo exit | sqlplus -s 'schema/password@tns' @'script_path'.
```

This is working fine in putty.

Comment: It is probably the return at the end of the line.  When you enter command in putty you are pressing the return key on the keyboard.  The command you are trying in c# doesn't have a return or using a different return.